# Using Query string in MVC 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some anchor tags in the page and I have to set them all a value in query string and then
trying to send it in controller can this be possible.Actually I have a hidden field on the page  and that hidden field is set to a value
when somebody selects a user from auto complete of jquery. Now my Question is that I am able to set hidden field a value but how can I assign value of hidden 
field to query string in an anchor tag. Please help me. I am trying in this way.

```
<div id="page">
   <div class="note-row2">
                <div class="form-left">
                    <input type="text" id="txt_Autocomplete" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="hdnPkClientId" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-right">
                </div>

<div class="right-row">
                <h3><a href="/GoToPage/Index?Client_ID="+"'$('#hdnPkClientId').val()'" >My Page</a></h3>
                   </div>
            </div>
</div>

Here I am setting the value in hidden field
<script>
  $("#txt_Autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/ClientHome/SearchClientDetail",
                    data: "{'searchtext':'" + document.getElementById('txt_Autocomplete').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.Data, function (item) {

                            return {

                                label: item.Name,
                                value: item.id,
                                data: item
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (xhr)
                    { }
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var detailArr = ui.item.label.split(',');
                $("#txt_Autocomplete").val(detailArr[0]);
                $("#hdnPkClientId").val(ui.item.data.Id);

</script>
```

I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your html:

```
<a id="YOUR_A" href="/GoToPage/Index?Client_ID=" >My Page</a>
```

in your js:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    var detailArr = ui.item.label.split(',');
    $("#txt_Autocomplete").val(detailArr[0]);
    $("#hdnPkClientId").val(ui.item.data.Id);
    $("#YOUR_A").attr("href", "/GoToPage/Index?Client_ID="+ui.item.data.Id);
}
```